# MapStruct: custom mapping function is applied to all fields

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have custom mapping function that maps `int` to `String`, but I only want it to be applied in one special case. However, it is applied to all source-fields of type int, not just the one annotated with `java(...)`.

Source class:

```
class Source {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    // getters etc...
}
```

Target class:

```
class Target {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    // getters etc...
}
```

Mapper:

```
@Mapping(source="a", target="a") // should not be necessary, but to make it more explicit
@Mapping(target="b", expression = "java(modify(b))")
public abstract Target sourceToTarget(Source source);

String modify(int value) {
    return "prefix_" + value;
}
```

What I want to achieve:

```
target.setA(String.valueOf(a));
target.setB(modify(b));
```

However, the generated code does this:

```
target.setA(modify(a));
target.setB(modify(b));
```

When removing the expression and `modify`, MapStruct uses `String.valueOf` for both values.
I tried it with both MapStruct `1.4.2.FINAL` as well as `1.5.2.FINAL`. Both classes make use of Lombok, however, this hasn't been a problem in the past.

Is this behavior expected? If yes, how else can I make it work?

Comment: `@Named` qualifier for `modify()` paired with `@Mapping#qualifiedByName` should solve your problem. Check official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can try :

--> `@Mapping#expression` Attribute :

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ExampleMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "b", expression = "java(modify(source.getB()))")
    @Mapping(target = "a", expression = "java(String.valueOf(source.getA()))")
    Target sourceToTarget(Source source);

    default String modify(int value) {
        return "prefix_" + value;
    }
}
```

It has generated this code :

```
@Component
public class ExampleMapperImpl implements ExampleMapper {

    @Override
    public Target sourceToTarget(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target target = new Target();

        target.setB( modify(source.getB()) );
        target.setA( String.valueOf(source.getA()) );

        return target;
    }
}
```

--> Try with `@Named` :

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ExampleMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "a", target = "a")
    @Mapping(target = "b", qualifiedByName = "any-name")
    Target sourceToTarget(Source source);

    @Named("any-name")
    default String modify(int value) {
        return "prefix_" + value;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have used `@Named` on `modify(int value)` method so that it can't be used by any mapping unless mentioned via `qualifiedByName`.

It has generated this code :

```
@Component
public class ExampleMapperImpl implements ExampleMapper {

    @Override
    public Target sourceToTarget(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target target = new Target();

        target.setA( String.valueOf( source.getA() ) );

        target.setB( modify(source.getB()) );

        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try this. Btw: I think you forgot to actually use `qualifiedByName` in your code example

Comment: @ceran It's not required. Without that also, it will generate

Comment: @ceran compiler will give error, if you use both qualifiedByName and expression in `@mapping`. So, you have to use either of them.

Comment: @ceran I have used `@Named` on modify method so that it can't be used by any mapping unless mentioned via qualified name or explicitly called via expression. Read my answer you will get it.

Comment: My point is, expression is not required anymore in the first place if you make use of `qualifiedByName`. From my understanding, that's the whole point of it. I will accept your answer, but I think the cleanest approach is `@Mapping(target="b", qualifiedByName("any-name"))` which works. Thanks